# Which smartphone apps have you found particularly useful when travelling (especially in New York)?

Tags: new-york-city, travel-tools, software

Which smartphone apps have you found useful when travelling? I'm thinking of travel-assistance (timetables. plans etc), finding interesting sights and eating-places, tips and tricks, virtual tour-guides - that kind of thing.

I use an Android device and will be travelling to New York next month so those items would interest me the most.

(question reformulated in attempt to make it less opinion-based)

Comment: I can't speak to which one for Android (on iOS I like Exit Strategy or Embark), but really, the main thing you need is a subway map application that works offline. Beyond that, your usual tools of Yelp, etc. should handle most of your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Yelp sounds interesting. What else is in the etc part of your reply? Complete noob on travel & review apps... (Why not reply as an answer rather than comment?)

Comment: @Vince it's just like a question asking for must-see places in New York. There is **no** right answer

Comment: @Dirty-flow mmh fine, so it's more that the OP needs to give more detailed expectations of what kind of apps. Might have been worth commenting how he can improve the question.

Comment: @paul this could be a good start http://mashable.com/2010/09/07/new-york-city-apps/

Comment: @paul I didn't write an answer because I don't know Android from R2D2. Yelp is just big enough to be on every platform. :P

Comment: @Vince There is no must haves because there are many apps providing many various things, Zagat, Yelp, Google Maps, Google Plus, Waze, and list goes on and on and on and on.  I use Android for the last 2 years I have tried quite a bit of various apps and selected a few that suit my needs.  They are available on all platforms since they have mostly nothing to do with Android Platform per se.  Those are provided to you by the manufacturer pre-installed.  So let's narrow down the criteria and then get the apps.

Comment: @Karlson I agree with asking for a category of app rather than an app (i.e. like in first comment, a kind of Yelp to find popular places and a subway app). And I think the change to mobile app is good, I am mostly wondering what could be a good format for such questions (I suppose there will be a lot, it's not so good if they're all closed fast).

Comment: @Vince the good format for the question would be like "I am looking for an app that will let me easily find such and so in someplace".  Problem with this question is that the OP is looking for everything.  Apps that do "everything" don't do any of that well.

Comment: Yeah I agree, that's a format we're not used to. But there is no point asking I want an app that does "that", that is where the subjectivity happens. Asking for what could be needed is, I think, a good question too. This is a way to phrase: what should I pack when I go on vacation?

Comment: @Vince There are always options even if there is just "that" to be requested.  In addition there are crosslinks from one service to another in mosts of them and so on and so forth.  I don't think that asking for an app that can find you restaurants around your location and reviews for them would make for a long list but would be a good question to ask.